# When i hover css menu horizontal scrollbar appears

Tags: html, css

Like the title says.

I made a css hover menu in the `<body>`, and i always want it in the top right corner of the browser.
But when i hover the menu the horizontal scrollbar appears down in  the browser.

Someone know why ?? and how to solve it ?

Here a link with a example: http://jsfiddle.net/pdbYz/24/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because of submenu's box-shadow, you have to clip it somehow

EDIT: it is because of `<div class="sub_menu_top"></div>`, you have to set it's position to `right:0`

Comment: Sorry even without the box shadow the horizontal scrollbar still appears (i mean the scrollbar down in the browser screen)

Answer (score 3):

Your overflowing your dirty sub menu...
try that :

```
div#sub_menu div.sub_menu_top {
    width:150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pdbYz/25/

Comment: As a good practice you should not use negative margins either and try to avoid absolute positioning as well. Oh and since i'm being mean, please use - instead of _ :-)

Comment: thhx i dindt see that the sub_menu_top the width was more then the sub_menu self lol i feel so stupid.

Comment: You don't have to avoid negative margins or positions absolute at all (at least in modern browsers)! You just have to know what you are doing ;-) I don't want do be harsh or anything, but this is really not true.

Comment: As I said, it is only as a good practice. When i debug some code and see position absolute, negative margins and underscores, I know in advance it's gonna be a pain in the arse to fix :) just by experience. But no in theory Sven is right

Comment: using position absolute on animated elements avoid content reflow, so it is rather a good practice

Comment: absolute appears twice in his code example so you're half right here :-)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with absolute positioning OR negative margins.

Answer (score 1):

```
div#sub_menu div.sub_menu_top {
    width:250px;
    height:13px;
    background-image:url(../images/arrow_up.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:109px bottom;
    position:absolute;
    top:-13px;
}
```

Remove `position:absolute;` and the scrollbar disappears.

Answer (score 1):

In the HMTL code on http://jsfiddle.net/pdbYz/24/, if you change the line

```
<div class="drop_down_block" id="sub_menu">
```

to

```
<div class="drop_down_block" id="sub_menu" style="position:fixed; right:0px;">
```

the scrollbar will not show when you hover over Menu.

You still need to figure out where to put the added CSS in your CSS file, but I guess you can do that pretty easily. If not, let me know and I will try and add more info.